# Show that $f(x)$ is a continuous probability density function

Tags: probability-distributions

continous probability

Suppose that $() =\frac {3}{8}x^2 \mathbb{1}_{(0;2)}(x)$

Show that () is a continuous probability
density function

Comment: This is unreadable.  Do you mean $f(x)=38x^2$?  Something else?

Comment: @lulu that's pretty creative you have to agree)

Comment: @Alex  What's interesting is that you can actually guess which symbols the OP left off.  I mean, there's really only $\frac 38x^2$ given that the integral must be $1$.

Comment: If you do not know the definition of continuous density functoin we cannot help. If you know the deifnition you should answer this yourself. I find it hard to believe that you have tried this before posting.

Comment: The density function that you have posted can take all possible values in the range between 1 and 2. Hence it is a continues function. If you still have doubts read about [Indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $f(x)> 0$ $\forall x \in (0;2)$

And

$$\int_0^2 \frac{3}{8}x^2 dx=1$$

End of the problem